# Can a DHCP server with a static IP assign itself an IP?

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

I am currently trying to configure a DHCP server for a small network A. Currently the DHCP for this network is handled by a local DHCP server, with the idea that this new DHCP server will take over the DHCP for this remote network A. This other server handles a network B. Currently the DHCP server for network B has a record for the "work in progress" DHCP server in A so that I can access it.

I know that the A Server should have a static IP address. My question is can I also have a record in server A that references itself? I know that once it has a properly configured static IP that it will still be accessible, but I am worried that in the process I will lose access to it (being a remote server). Also for my own sanity I find it easier to have a self referential record in the list of hosts for itself.

So the question is, will I create an issues within my DHCP server by having a reference to the server itself in the records? I accept to the answer to this question may explain something that I am misunderstanding about the configuration of DHCP servers, so if that is the case hopefully I can understand it better as a result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So the question is, will I create an issues within my DHCP server by having a reference to the server itself in the records?

No. You **can** create a static host record in the dhcpd configuration for the dhcp server nic. You should **not** attempt to obtain an ip on the dhcp from itself via dhcp. The dhcp server ip should remain hard coded in the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

If your DHCP server hasn't already assigned a (fixed or DHCP) IP, the DHCP server will fail to bind to the interface / address and so will fail to start.